# How to Slide one item in while another item is sliding out

Tags: wpf, xaml, slideshow

I was hoping that I could get some guidance.  I am trying to make an image control that has left and right buttons on it that will cause the image that is showing to slide out of view (either left or right) and at the same time slide the 'next' image in (similar to what 'WowSlider' can do. (http://wowslider.com/image-gallery-simple-basic-demo.html)).

I am working in WPF 4.5 and I would like some helpful insights.

Thank you very much,
Tim

Comment: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/354702/WPF-Slideshow

Comment: http://richapps.wordpress.com/2009/02/27/wpf-image-gallery/

Comment: Thank you har07. I looked at both of those implementations and while I found them informative, I don't believe that they are what I am looking for. I will continue looking.